# Divisibility via Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

Let $N$ be a large natural number, let $A$ be a subset of naturals, and ask:

> How many numbers $n\leq N$ are divisible by one or more numbers in $A$.

This is a [classical application of the Inclusion-Exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion-exclusion_principle#Examples).  Indeed, if for each $i$ we set $A_i$ to be those numbers $n\leq N$ divisible by $i$, then $A_{i_1} \cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k} = A_k$ where $k$ is the lcm of the $i_j$ and so it's easy to evaluate
$$ \Big| \bigcup_{i\in A} A_i\Big| = \sum_{\emptyset\not=B\subset A} (-1)^{1+|B|} \Big| \bigcap_{i\in B} A_i\Big| $$
However, this will take around $2^{|A|}$ time and so if $A$ is large, it becomes intractable.

There is something odd in my mind though: what if $A$ is all numbers between 2 and 100?  Well, then we don't need to check divisibility by 4, as checking for 2 is enough.  Continuing, we see that actually we can replace $A$ be the set of primes less than 100, and I strongly suspect we can't do better (as we end up simulating a sieving method, basically).  But what if $A$ is the numbers between 51 and 100?  Then there seems no naive reduction, and this becomes *worse* than testing for the bigger set of all numbers between 2 and 100.

> Is there a more sophisticated method?  Especially when $A=[51,100]$ or similar examples.